# Custom backup for RTMP-push streams with nginx-rtmp-module

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, rtmp, live-streaming

I need to backup RTMP streams that I send to my server (nginx with nginx-rtmp-module): in case one of them fails, I need another to be automatically substituted when I grab it from the server.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out a bit tricky way to do this and put [the solution on Github](https://github.com/ngoral/nginx-rtmp-backup)

It is a bunch of Shell scripts that allows you to do the following (assuming your server has DNS `yourserver.ex`:

Send your main stream to `rtmp://yourserver.ex/main/somekey`, backup stream to `rtmp://yourserver.ex/backup/somekey` and watch the result on `rtmp://yourserver.ex/out/somekey`. (More instructions on Github)

There could be a slight delay in switching streams, however, it works better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing stream failover can be done in a simple, reliable, and flexible way using FFmpeg with Nginx. For example, you might have two streams:

- `rtmp://ip/app/stream1`
- `rtmp://ip/app/stream2`

For redundancy, you would typically use two separate OBS instances or camera devices, each streaming to one of these addresses. The actual broadcast stream would be a third stream:

- `rtmp://ip/app/production`

You can switch between the streams using a single FFmpeg instance with a simple script:

```bash
while TRUE; do
  ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://ip/app/stream1 -c copy -f flv rtmp://ip/app/production;
  ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://ip/app/stream2 -c copy -f flv rtmp://ip/app/production;
  sleep 0.5;
done
```

This solution is highly scalable, for example:

- If both stream1 and stream2 are on the same server, you can distribute them across two different servers for failover.
- You can run multiple scripts to push streams to multiple production servers, providing multiple available sources for service.
- It supports not only RTMP and Nginx but also other protocols like SRT and other servers.

One weakness of this solution is that the switch time and content may be duplicated or missing. To address this, you can reduce the stream latency. For example, if both streams have a latency within 500ms, the content change will be imperceptible to the viewer. You can use the SRT protocol to achieve this, replacing all streams with SRT:

- `srt://ip?streamid=#!::r=app/stream1,m=publish`
- `srt://ip?streamid=#!::r=app/stream2,m=publish`
- `srt://ip?streamid=#!::r=app/production,m=publish`

You will need to convert the SRT protocol to RTMP or HLS to integrate with existing systems. You can use the SRS streaming server for this, see [SRS: SRT](https://ossrs.net/lts/zh-cn/docs/v6/doc/srt).

> Note: If your device does not support SRT, you can consider using WebRTC (WHIP) by replacing the addresses with WHIP. See [SRS: WHIP](https://ossrs.net/lts/zh-cn/docs/v6/doc/webrtc).

This solution is not limited to Nginx and can be used with any streaming server that supports these protocols, as the core functionality relies on FFmpeg.

Besides Nginx RTMP, there is another one-click solution, you only need to publish to SRS Stack by RTMP, SRT, or WHIP, then it can forward or provide a output stream, which is exactly use this FFmpeg solution, please see [SRS Stack: Multiple Streaming](https://blog.ossrs.io/maximize-your-live-streaming-reach-a-guide-to-multi-platform-streaming-38be22beec57)